# Htaccess redirect /en/ to /fr/ for one domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site and I want to redirect:

http://mywebsite.com/en/content/xxx-random-things.php

to

http://mywebsite.com/fr/content/xxx-random-things.php

So everything after /en/ get after /fr/

That's all.
Thanks you

Comment: Do you have anything in your current .htaccess? If so, add relevant parts of it here to the question.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^en/(.+)$ /fr/$1`

Comment: That looks all right. Do you have enabled `mod_rewrite` module in PHP and `RewriteEngine On` before this line in .htaccess? Also, do you have the .htaccess in root folder of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the follwoing code at the main directory  mywebsite.com/.htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^boutique/en/(.*)$ /boutique/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Another solution is to put the following code at  mywebsite.com/boutique/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And you can do it by another way to redirect every thing at en to fr by putting code in en directory  mywebsite.com/boutique/en/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1  [L,R=301]
```

Note :one of them is quite enough

Comment: Thanks but actually this is not working.My website is like http://mywebsite.com/boutique/en/some-random-things.php and need to go like http://mywebsite.com/boutique/fr/some-random-things.php

Comment: So this work for you , just in   mywebsite.com/boutique/ .htaccess file the first code , or you can put the second code at  mywebsite.com/boutique/en/.htaccess file

Comment: please see the edit and i am sure if you do every thing as it is , it will work fine